# How to create a count-up effect for a textView in Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am working on an app that counts the number of questions marks in a few paragraphs of text.

After the scanning is done (which takes no time at all) I would love to have the total presented after the number goes from 0 to TOTAL. So, for 10: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 *10* and then STOP.

I have tried a couple of different techniques:

```
                TextView sentScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sentScore);

                long freezeTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

                for (int i = 0; i < sent; i++) {
                    if ((SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - freezeTime) > 500) {
                        sentScore.setText(sent.toString());
                    }
                }
```

Also I tried this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < sent; i++) { 
        // try {
            Thread.sleep(500);

        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            sentScore.setText(i.toString()); 
        } 
    }
```

I am sure these are both completely amateur attempts. Any help would be much-appreciated.

Thanks,

Richard

Comment: If you're using the sleep method on the UI thread, so the main thread of your app, then don't. It will block the interface and the user won't be able to do anything in that time.

Comment: That is exactly what happened. Any idea/s on how I can achieve the effect I am looking for?

Comment: It's very late here and i'm tired so i can't folllow exactly what you want to do but to avoid the interface from freezing, you must set the sleep method in a separate thread. Either create one and put you sleep method there, or i'm not sure as i used it a long time ago, there is some type of timer either from Java or from Android platform which automatically creates a separate thread and you can attach a callback function so it executes that every 500 miliseconds. Just google java timers or android timers or just wait for someone here to tell you :P haha. I'm 2 tired right now :)

Comment: try this https://github.com/uguratar/countingtextview

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
private int counter = 0;
private int total = 30; // the total number
//...
//when you want to start the counting start the thread bellow.
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    while (counter < total) {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(500);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        t.post(new Runnable() {

                            public void run() {
                                t.setText("" + counter);

                            }

                        });
                        counter++;
                    }

                }

            }).start();
```

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to write that. Right now I have a method that gets the text-messages and counts the messages called: `protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {` do I want to initiate the thread after that? Or within it? I can't seem to get it work if I start the runnable thread from within that method.

Comment: @burtonic There shouldn't be a problem starting the thread from that callback method, when you get the total number then start the thread.(`onActivityResult` is a callback method, called when you expect something from a child activity that your started with startActivityForResult()). Note that the `TextView` should be `final` so you can access it from that anonymous class.

Comment: A little bit of re-jigging and it works *exactly* how I wanted it to. Thank you! http://cl.ly/0X0H0M1Y3Y3L1j3g1C2d

Comment: Isn't it better to use Animator instead of handle it directly? I have also read that Thread is bad, use Handler instead for Android.

Comment: @HendraWD My answer was posted in 2012, obviously the current Animator class is a better choice(look at marmor's answer). A Thread and a Handler aren't the same thing so I don't understand what you intended to say with this.

Comment: @Luksprog ok thanks for your confirmation. Yes, Thread and Handler are different thing, but Handler can replace Thread. https://blog.mindorks.com/android-core-looper-handler-and-handlerthread-bd54d69fe91a www.mopri.de/2010/timertask-bad-do-it-the-android-way-use-a-handler/

Answer (score 61):

I've used a more conventional Android-style animation for this:

```
        ValueAnimator animator = new ValueAnimator();
        animator.setObjectValues(0, count);
        animator.addUpdateListener(new AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                view.setText(String.valueOf(animation.getAnimatedValue()));
            }
        });
        animator.setEvaluator(new TypeEvaluator<Integer>() {
            public Integer evaluate(float fraction, Integer startValue, Integer endValue) {
                return Math.round(startValue + (endValue - startValue) * fraction);
            }
        });
        animator.setDuration(1000);
        animator.start();
```

You can play with the `0` and `count` values to make the counter go from any number to any number, and play with the `1000` to set the duration of the entire animation.

Note that this supports Android API level 11 and above, but you can use the awesome [nineoldandroids](http://nineoldandroids.com/) project to make it backward compatible easily.

Comment: If the startValue is other than 0, it does not work correctly. You have to update the evaluate function to return startValue + (endValue - startValue) * fraction. Other than that great work!

Comment: how it works on double? i get the error java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

Comment: you need to change the TypeEvaluator to TypeEvaluator<Float> and return a float from the evaluate method

Answer (score 4):

The question is very old, but I am posting this so that it would help someone else. 
I have used these 2 amazing libraries.

Try them

1. https://github.com/MasayukiSuda/CountAnimationTextView

[image: Sample Effect]

Or
2. https://github.com/robinhood/ticker

[image: Sample effect of 2nd library]

Hope this helps :)  Happy Coding!!!

Answer (score 2):

Use [TextSitcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextSwitcher.html)

for the best effects. It will transform the text softly.

When coming to the change of the text use the below Code.

```
> int number = 0;
>         Timer obj = new Timer();
>         TimerTask tt = new TimerTask() {
>                       @Override           public void run() {
>               // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>               textView.setText(number++);
>               if(number < score)
>               obj.schedule(tt, 200);          }       };
>         obj.schedule(tt, 200);
```

Comment: I believe you meant ```TextSwitcher``` right? You should have posted a more complete fragment of code showing the use of it. But still, points for mentioning that sweet sweet class :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a worker thread to do the waiting and update your UI thread.

You could use an AsyncTask, though it might be an overkill for this job. If you use this, In the doInBackground() loop over the number of sleep periods and after every sleep period, update the count in the UIthread.

There you go! Slukain just gave you the working code :P

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try changing the for loop to something like:

```
int count = 0;
while (count != sent) {
    if ((SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - freezeTime) > 500) {
        count++;
        sentScore.setText("" + count);
        freezeTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that just pushes the correct total to the view immediately. I had to change sentScore to sent. That is the name of the variable that holds the total.

Comment: using a separate thread and sleeping is better, as slukian has just posted.