# Android CountDownTimer is too fast for textView update

Tags: android, timer, countdown, countdowntimer, settext

im trying to implement timer using android, such that it will countdown from given number to 0, to do it i use CountDownTimer... the problem is that i want it to be updated every 1 millisecond and it seems that the textView that i use to present the time is to slow when i try to setText... for example if i start the timer from 20000 and se 1 millisecond as countDownInterval the textView stops changing when it gets to approx 19000..

here is my code:

```
currTimer=new CountDownTimer(20000,10) {

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                scoreBoard.setCurrMilliTime(scoreBoard.getCurrMilliTime()-10);
                textView.setText(Integer.toString(scoreBoard.getCurrMilliTime()));

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                scoreBoard.setCurrMilliTime(scoreBoard.getCurrMilliTime()-10);
                textView.setText(Integer.toString(scoreBoard.getCurrMilliTime()));

            }
        }.start();
```

Comment: "i want it to be updated every 1 millisecond " -- why? Humans cannot see changes that fast.

Comment: even if i change it to 10 or 100 it still stops before reaching 0 in the textView

Comment: Well, you need to set your final value in `onFinish()`.

Comment: i know, but its a small change and it should stop on the time interval  i send if this would work but it stops a lot before.

Comment: @CommonsWare humans can see change that fast. For example when updating my progress bar based on a countdown timer it matters

Comment: @MobileMon: Complex. Trained Aircraft pilots can _identify_ planes flashed for 1/220th of a second on a dark wall. http://www.100fps.com/how_many_frames_can_humans_see.htm Televisions only aim for a bit above 48Hz to avoid flicker, since it's harder to notice darkness than a flash of light. 
Mostly moot since Android targets 60fps regardless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried this :

```
final TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    new CountDownTimer(20000,10) {

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            textView1.setText(String.format("%d : %d :%d", 
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished),

                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) - 
                    TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished)), 

                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMillis(millisUntilFinished) - 
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) - 
                            TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished)))
                ));

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

        }
    }.start();
```

and works perfectly, hope this helps, although i don't think a step by "10" is average enough, try 100

Comment: To get the milliseconds the correct code is: 
TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMillis(millisUntilFinished) -
                                        TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished))

Answer (score 0):

Use an animation, which is designed to change something on the screen a tiny bit every frame, which is perfect for what you're doing.
Sample blatantly plagarized from https://stackoverflow.com/a/24389011/845092

```
    ValueAnimator animator = new ValueAnimator();
    animator.setObjectValues(0, count);
    animator.addUpdateListener(new AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            view.setText(String.valueOf(animation.getAnimatedValue()));
        }
    });
    animator.setEvaluator(new TypeEvaluator<Integer>() {
        public Integer evaluate(float fraction, Integer startValue, Integer endValue) {
            return Math.round(startValue + (endValue - startValue) * fraction);
        }
    });
    animator.setDuration(1000);
    animator.start();
```